# Surrounding JTextPane with images

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm working on a project on my own and wanted to create an JComponent or JFrame that looks like the the screenshot provided in the link(since it says here I don't have enough reputation to post images). The JTextPane is surrounded by three pictures and it does wrap words to next line.

So please help me.I would appreciate if you demonstrated your answer with an example.
Here are the links to the images.

Layout
[image: Layout]
Screen Shot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution might be to create a `JLabel` and set its `icon` property to the background image...

```
Icon icon = ...;
JLabel background = new JLabel(icon);
```

Set the label's layout manager to something like `GridBagLayout`...

```
background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Set the `GridBagConstraints` insets so that the text pane will be offset within the contain...

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
```

And then simply add the `JTextPane` to the label...

```
JTextPane textPane = ...;
background.add(textPane, gbc);
```

You can then either add the `JLabel` to the what ever container you want or even set it as the `JFrame`'s content pane depending on your needs.

ps- You'll need to make the text pane transparent...

For example...

[image: Background pane]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class TextPaneWrapped {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextPaneWrapped();
    }

    public TextPaneWrapped() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                try {
                    JLabel background = new JLabel(
                            new ImageIcon(
                                    ImageIO.read(
                                            new File("background.jpg"))));
                    background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

                    JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
                    textPane.setOpaque(false);

                    Style centerStyle = textPane.addStyle("center", null);
                    StyleConstants.setAlignment(centerStyle, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
                    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(centerStyle, textPane.getFont().getFamily());
                    textPane.setParagraphAttributes(centerStyle, true);

                    Style defaultStyle = textPane.addStyle("defaultStyle", centerStyle);
                    StyleConstants.setFontSize(defaultStyle, 24);

                    Style capWord = textPane.addStyle("capWord", defaultStyle);
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(capWord, Color.RED);
                    StyleConstants.setFontSize(capWord, 48);

                    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
                    try {
                        doc.insertString(0, "H", capWord);
                        doc.insertString(1, "ello ", defaultStyle);
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "W", capWord);
                        doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "orld", defaultStyle);
                    } catch (BadLocationException exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                    gbc.insets = new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40);
                    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                    gbc.weightx = 1;
                    gbc.weighty = 1;
                    background.add(textPane, gbc);

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(background);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I was hoping to use GridBagLayout put that didn't correctly display the pictures.

Comment: @user3380414 The problem you might have is getting the images to align back up with each other.  This would be a problem if the `JTextPane` wasn't in a `JScrollPane` as it will want to continually change size as you change the content...

Comment: @user3380414 You've also got to remember that the size of a font (in pixels) will be different between different platforms/rendering pipelines, making it very difficult to rely on a layout manager to accurately line up the separate images. Remember, you should never try to achieve pixel perfect layouts, it will just keep byting your in the rear...

Comment: your answer is very wonderful and I liked the way you styled the text pane. But one more thing, I want the JTextPane to continue horizontally when the space doesn't fit instead of wrapping the words to the next line. How do I achieve that in this example? Thx

Comment: [crossposted](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/474477/help-with-swing)

Comment: See [No Wrap Text Pane](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/no-wrap-text-pane/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I used the method in the link you provided and I works.But the ScrollPane is opaque even though I tried to make it(& the JPanel) transparent by using setOpaque(false). Here is what I have got so far, http://www.4shared.com/download/nh6t18Ajba/textWrap.JPG?lgfp=3000. Can I make the ScrollPane transparent so that for the background picture to be visible?

Comment: Make sure you make he scroll pane, it's viewport and the text pane are all transparent