# How to change the font color of a single line inside a JTextArea?

Tags: java, fonts, jtextarea, foreground

I have a JTextArea object that i use to print out messages to the user.
I would like to change the color of the exception messages to red.
when I use `msgArea.setForeground(Color.red);` before a specific message, it changes the color of all message lines to red, not only that specific one.
this is the part where I try to change the color:

```
public void openport(){
    try {   
        SP.openPort();
        SP.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        SP.addEventListener(new SerialPortReader(),SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);

    } 
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {msgArea.setForeground(Color.red);
        msgArea.append(ex.toString());
        } 
    catch (IOException ex) {msgArea.append(ex.toString());}
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `JTextArea` is design to display plain text, you will need to use either a `JTextPane` or `JEditorPane` to make it work

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184448/surrounding-jtextpane-with-images/22185053#22185053) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948148/jeditorpane-set-foreground-color-for-different-words/18948340#18948340)