# Compare a short and a long string in JTextPane and write characters of the long string in an other color

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, styleddocument

I hope you can help me to solve my Problem.

I have two Strings and both are nearly equal.

String A is like: "*Hello my friend*"

String B is like: "*Hello! my! friend*"

Now I want to compare both Strings and write the result into another String.
The result must be the String B with all diffent characters from String A in blue Color.

The "!" is for example. "!" could be any Kind of text including whitespaces.

I have to realize this with a `JTextPane/StyledDocument`.

Can you give me some examples or ideas to get this?

Thank you.

Comment: So what would be the result of your example: "**Hello**! my! friend!" or "**Hello**! **my**! **friend**"? Aka would an "friend" at a different index be considered a "difference" for you.

Comment: The resut must be "Hello! my! friend" but the "!" are blue.

Comment: I'm left wondering, is your google broken - I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184448/surrounding-jtextpane-with-images/22185053#22185053)

Comment: Sorry @MadProgrammer I've found nothing to solve my problem. 
The example is good, but I can't solve my problem with it.

Comment: @morlog47 Well, you're not going to find the "perfect" solution to your problem, you're going to have to solve small parts of it, the example demonstrates how to interact with a `StyledDocument` which would at least be a "starting" point, I suggest having a going and seeing what you can do

Comment: (1-) `I've found nothing to solve my problem.` - well of course you will need to write the algorithm to find the "different" characters. Finding the characters to highlight is a non trivial exercise depending on your exact requirement of what a match/difference is. However, highlighting the character once you find them is easily demonstrated in that link, or you can just use the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more examples.

Comment: @camickr Writing the algorithm for that is my problem. That is the reason why I'm asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing chars one by one, applying a new style to every single char? That might be dirty but it's easy and that kinda solves your problem.

If it's an algorithmic problem - I don't think it is, but still - you should use a third string in which you add every character of `String A` and when you encounter a difference, you add the character from `B` and decrease your iterator on `A`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @BilalAhmed sorry but I'm new to stackoverflow, and I don't have the right to comment. Would love to~